# how to not have both divs open at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When a user clicks to sign in and when the user clicks because he forgets the password both divs `sign_in` and `forgot_password` can open. Everything works fine except I only want one to be open at the time while the other one is closed. How can I have only one open at one time if I start clicking on both divs ? Thanks in advance !

```
<a href="#" onclick="showhide('sign_in'); return(false);">Sign In</a>

<a href="#" onclick="showhide('forgot_password'); return(false);">Forgot Password?</a>

<div id="sign_in" style="display:none;">
 <iframe name="user_content_login" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" src="some_user_file.html" height="195"></iframe>
</div>

<div id="forgot_password" style="display:none;">
<iframe name="user_content_forgot_password"   frameborder="no" scrolling="no" src="some_forgot_password_file.html" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: what does `showhide` look like?

Comment: What is the javascript code of your `showhide` function?

Comment: when you click on one show it and hide the other and vice versa

Answer (score 2):

As this is marked jQuery, first let's remove the inline JavaScript from the markup and instead use a class to reference the elements by

```
<a href="#sign_in" class=show-hide>Sign In</a>

<a href="#forgot_password" class=show-hide>Forgot Password?</a>
```

you can probably remove the DIVs and assign the IDs to the IFRAMEs, but then again you probably shouldn't be using IFRAMEs anyway, but that's a different topic, anyway let's group the targets with a class named `target`

```
<div id="sign_in" style="display:none;" class=target>
 <iframe name="user_content_login" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" src="some_user_file.html" height="195"></iframe>
</div>

<div id="forgot_password" style="display:none;" class=target>
<iframe name="user_content_forgot_password" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" src="some_forgot_password_file.html" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

[sidenote: you could remove the inline styles (`style="display:none;"`)  from the DIVs and put that in your CSS file `.target{display:none}`]

This is an example how the jQuery could look like:

```
$('.show-hide').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent from window jumping to the div or the location bar changing
    $('.target').hide(); //hide both divs
    $($(this).attr('href')).show(); //show the div with the id of the clicked links href 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just simplify it and do something like below. Adjust as needed.

**Basic show/hide**

```js
$('li').click(function() {
  $('#credentials div:visible').hide(); // Hide the visible div
  $('#credentials div').eq($(this).index()).show(); 
// The above line shows the corresponding div to the clicked LI
});
```

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#login,
#recover-password {
  font-size: 36px;
  color: red;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
}
#credentials div:last-of-type {
  display: none;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="credentials">

  <ul>
    <li>Sign in</li>
    <li>Forgot password</li>



  </ul>


  <div id="login">

    Login form goes here

  </div>
  <!-- End Login Form -->

  <div id="recover-password">

    Recovery form goes here

  </div>
  <!-- End Login Form -->

</div>
<!-- Credentials End here -->
```

**With some animation:**

```js
$('li').click(function() {
  $('#credentials div:visible').hide();
  $('#credentials div').eq($(this).index()).show(1000);
// Regulating the speed adds some animation to it
});
```

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#login,
#recover-password {
  font-size: 36px;
  color: red;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
}
#credentials div:last-of-type {
  display: none;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="credentials">

  <ul>
    <li>Sign in</li>
    <li>Forgot password</li>



  </ul>


  <div id="login">

    Login form goes here

  </div>
  <!-- End Login Form -->

  <div id="recover-password">

    Recovery form goes here

  </div>
  <!-- End Login Form -->

</div>
<!-- Credentials End here -->
```

**Note:** You could fadeOut the visible element and fadeIn the corresponding element to the one that  has been clicked.